# Optimizing row_number to not scan all table

Tags: postgresql, performance, sorting, multi-index, postgresql-performance

I have a table created as

```
CREATE TABLE T0
(
    id text,
    kind_of_datetime text,
    ... 10 more text fields
),
PRIMARY KEY(id, kind_of_datetime)
```

It is about 31M rows with about 800K of unique `id` values and 13K unique `kind_of_datetime` values.

I want to make query

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY kind_of_datetime DESC) as rn_col
    FROM TO
    WHERE kind_of_datetime <= 'some_value'
) as tmp
WHERE rn_col = 1
```

It makes `WindowAgg` with actual reading of all table + sorting and works really long (minutes).

I tried to make index

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON T0 (id, kind_of_datetime DESC NULLS LAST)
```

and in works better but only if final select consists of two key columns `id + kind_of_datetime`. Otherwise it's always fullscan.

Maybe I should change a way of storing data? Or create some other index?

What I don't want to do is to add `UNCLUDE 10 other columns` because it will take much RAM.

Comment: See [Slow Query Questions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions#Guide_to_Asking_Slow_Query_Questions) and provide the information shown there.

Answer (score 0):

Try a subquery:

```
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY kind_of_datetime DESC) as rn_col
FROM (SELECT * FROM tab
      WHERE kind_of_datetime <= 'some_value'
     ) AS t
```

That will definitely apply the filter first.